# Read with fgets() until \n

Tags: c

I need to read a line up to 128 bytes in chunks of 16 bytes and I was recommended to use fgets but I have 2 mayor problems with it.

First, it doesn't stop reading when it detects the \n. I need it to work with the Linux terminal and if a use for example

> echo "ls -l\nls -l\nls -l" | ./mycode

What I expect to see as stdout is the 3 commands in different lines, but what I see is "ls -l\nls -l\nls" as a first line, and " -l" as a second line. And I need my code to work this exact input (and many others but this is just an example). So I need the code to recognize the \n and stop reading in that exact point until I tell the program to continue reading.

This is what I have right now made as a test:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BUF_SIZE 16

int main(){
    char *buf = malloc(sizeof(char) * BUF_SIZE);
    while((fgets(buf, BUF_SIZE + 1, stdin)) != NULL){
        fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", buf);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Also, once I can read the line until newline without problems, I also need to combine all the parts read in a variable of also the `char *` type.

Comment: The `+1` is wrong, though it's probably not your immediate problem.

Comment: you may want to try `$ echo -e "ls -l\nls -l\nls -l" | ./mycode` ... https://i2.paste.pics/73538ca3e832815eb6a85a2d3a370230.png

Comment: Previously [How can I read from stdin until new line in groups of 16 bytes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73998696/how-can-i-read-from-stdin-until-new-line-in-groups-of-16-bytes-c)

Comment: I have already included the stdib but I haven't written the includes. And what do you refer to warnings? Also, I can't use the -e. One of the test the program has to pass is the exact command I wrote in the question

Comment: Then you're out of luck. Because without the `-e` it sends the literal characters \ and n.

Comment: pmg meant: do include this **in your question**. We cannot see the code you have on your computer, only the code you posted here. The question should include a [mre]. If we copy-paste your original code, we get `error: ‘stdin’ undeclared`. However, we should be able to copy-paste your example code and run it without having to manually modify it. The cast is also unnecessary and distracting. I fixed both issues now, but please make sure to do this yourself the next time you post a question here. Thanks.

Comment: You will need at least 128 bytes of memory to do this, and probably 129 for convenience of working with a NUL-terminated string. It doesn't matter what granularity you read input with, it matters what size the maximum input is.

Comment: Are you talking about a dfa that recognizes two symbols, `[^\\\x00]+`, `[\\n]`? Like, literally { '\\', 'n' }?

Answer (score 0):

> I need to read a line up to 128 bytes in chunks of 16 bytes and I was recommended to use fgets but I have 2 mayor problems with it.

> First, it doesn't stop reading when it detects the \n

That is simply *incorrect*. This has been mentioned by me [and *others*] in the prior question.

Once again, `fgets` will *stop* when it sees `\n`.

The code you have above that uses `fgets` has UB (undefined behavior). It allocates a buffer of length 16. But, it passes `16 + 1` to `fgets`. This means `fgets` can read pass the end of the buffer causing UB (i.e. a *bug*).

You want the same length in both cases. And, if you want a 16 byte chunk of *data*, the length you want to pass is [probably] 17.

Referring to the prior question as well, which has an `fgets` solution from me: [How can I read from stdin until new line in groups of 16 bytes? c](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73999343/5382650)

---

You seem to want to use a solution that loops on `read` in 16 byte chunks that stops on `\n`. In other words, your teacher wants you to *implement* your own `fgets` function.

The crux of the problem is that you need a `struct` that remembers state across calls. It has to have a "hold" buffer that `read` puts data into, maintaining an offset and length for the buffer. When a newline is detected, the data has to be copied out. The length is adjusted and the remaining chars [read in by `read` but *not* passed to caller] must be moved to the front of the buffer.

Here is a test program that does that. It is a bit crude:

1. It ignores the `mode` argument.
2. It [probably] doesn't handle the final line correctly if it does *not* end with a newline.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#ifdef DEBUG
#define dbgprt(_fmt...) \
    printf(_fmt)
#else
#define dbgprt(_fmt...) \
    do { } while (0)
#endif

char buf[128 + 1];

typedef struct {
    int fd;
    int eof;
    size_t len;
    char buf[4096];
} XFIL;

char *
fix(const char *str,int len)
{
    static char buf[4096];
    char *bp = buf;

    if (len < 0)
        len = strlen(str);

    for (int idx = 0;  idx < len;  ++idx) {
        int chr = str[idx];

        if (chr == 0)
            break;

        if ((chr >= 0x20) && (chr <= 0x7E))
            *bp++ = chr;
        else
            bp += sprintf(bp,"{%2.2X}",chr & 0xFF);
    }

    *bp = 0;

    return buf;
}

XFIL *
xopen(const char *file,const char *mode)
{
    XFIL *xf = calloc(1,sizeof(*xf));

    xf->fd = open(file,O_RDONLY);

    return xf;
}

char *
xfgets(char *buf,size_t maxlen,XFIL *xf)
{
    size_t off = xf->len;
    ssize_t rdlen;
    size_t curlen;
    char *bp;
    char *nl;
    char *ret = NULL;

    dbgprt("xfgets: ENTER maxlen=%zu eof=%d\n",maxlen,xf->eof);

    while (1) {
        dbgprt("xfgets: LOOP off=%zu eof=%d\n",off,xf->eof);

        // find newline if we have one
        if (xf->len > 0)
            nl = memchr(xf->buf,'\n',xf->len);
        else
            nl = NULL;

        // found a newline
        if (nl != NULL) {
            // get amount of data in buffer up to and including the newline
            curlen = (nl - xf->buf) + 1;
            dbgprt("xfgets: NLMATCH curlen=%zu\n",curlen);

            // copy this out to caller's buffer (and add EOS)
            memcpy(buf,xf->buf,curlen);
            buf[curlen] = 0;
            dbgprt("xfgets: RET buf='%s'\n",fix(buf,-1));

            // set up return pointer
            ret = buf;

            // get amount of data remaining in our buffer
            curlen = xf->len - curlen;
            dbgprt("xfgets: REMLEN curlen=%zu\n",curlen);

            // slide this to the front of our buffer
            memmove(xf->buf,nl + 1,curlen);
            dbgprt("xfgets: HOLD bf='%s'\n",fix(xf->buf,curlen));

            xf->len = curlen;
            break;
        }

        if (xf->eof)
            break;

        // read next chunk of file
        bp = xf->buf + off;

        rdlen = read(xf->fd,bp,16);
        dbgprt("xfgets: READ rdlen=%zd\n",rdlen);

        if (rdlen < 0) {
            ret = NULL;
            xf->eof = 1;
            break;
        }

        dbgprt("xfgets: DATA bp='%s'\n",fix(bp,rdlen));
        if (rdlen == 0)
            xf->eof = 1;

        // advance number of bytes in the hold buffer
        xf->len += rdlen;

        // advance offset into buffer
        off += rdlen;
    }

    dbgprt("xfgets: EXIT ret=%p\n",ret);

    return ret;
}

int
main(void)
{

    const char *file = "inp.txt";
    FILE *fin = fopen(file,"r");
    XFIL *xf = xopen(file,"r");

    char buf[2][1000];
    char *ret[2];

    while (1) {
        ret[0] = fgets(buf[0],1000,fin);
        ret[1] = xfgets(buf[1],1000,xf);

        printf("main: RET %p/%p\n",ret[0],ret[1]);
        if ((ret[0] != NULL) != (ret[1] != NULL))
            break;

        if (ret[0] == NULL)
            break;

        printf("BUF0: %s\n",fix(buf[0],-1));
        printf("BUF1: %s\n",fix(buf[1],-1));

        if (strcmp(buf[0],buf[1]) != 0) {
            printf("error\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

Here is the test input:

```
abc
def
ghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
qrm
```

---

Here is the program output [with `-DDEBUG`]. I've indented it manually a bit to show the call sequence:

```
xfgets: ENTER maxlen=1000 eof=0
  xfgets: LOOP off=0 eof=0
  xfgets: READ rdlen=16
  xfgets: DATA bp='abc{0A}def{0A}ghijklmn'
  xfgets: LOOP off=16 eof=0
  xfgets: NLMATCH curlen=4
  xfgets: RET buf='abc{0A}'
  xfgets: REMLEN curlen=12
  xfgets: HOLD bf='def{0A}ghijklmn'
xfgets: EXIT ret=0x7fff5d044d48
main: RET 0x7fff5d044960/0x7fff5d044d48
BUF0: abc{0A}
BUF1: abc{0A}
xfgets: ENTER maxlen=1000 eof=0
  xfgets: LOOP off=12 eof=0
  xfgets: NLMATCH curlen=4
  xfgets: RET buf='def{0A}'
  xfgets: REMLEN curlen=8
  xfgets: HOLD bf='ghijklmn'
xfgets: EXIT ret=0x7fff5d044d48
main: RET 0x7fff5d044960/0x7fff5d044d48
BUF0: def{0A}
BUF1: def{0A}
xfgets: ENTER maxlen=1000 eof=0
  xfgets: LOOP off=8 eof=0
  xfgets: READ rdlen=16
  xfgets: DATA bp='opqrstuvwxyz{0A}qrm'
  xfgets: LOOP off=24 eof=0
  xfgets: NLMATCH curlen=21
  xfgets: RET buf='ghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{0A}'
  xfgets: REMLEN curlen=3
  xfgets: HOLD bf='qrm'
xfgets: EXIT ret=0x7fff5d044d48
main: RET 0x7fff5d044960/0x7fff5d044d48
BUF0: ghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{0A}
BUF1: ghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{0A}
xfgets: ENTER maxlen=1000 eof=0
  xfgets: LOOP off=3 eof=0
  xfgets: READ rdlen=1
  xfgets: DATA bp='{0A}'
  xfgets: LOOP off=4 eof=0
  xfgets: NLMATCH curlen=4
  xfgets: RET buf='qrm{0A}'
  xfgets: REMLEN curlen=0
  xfgets: HOLD bf=''
xfgets: EXIT ret=0x7fff5d044d48
main: RET 0x7fff5d044960/0x7fff5d044d48
BUF0: qrm{0A}
BUF1: qrm{0A}
xfgets: ENTER maxlen=1000 eof=0
  xfgets: LOOP off=0 eof=0
  xfgets: READ rdlen=0
  xfgets: DATA bp=''
  xfgets: LOOP off=0 eof=1
xfgets: EXIT ret=(nil)
main: RET (nil)/(nil)
```